# How to convert an 24bit RGB color to the closest matching 12-bit (4096) shades?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, image-processing, colors, rgb

I have a Video to ASCII script in java-script, where i use 8bit gray-scale algorithm for ASCII video output.

```
gcolor = ~~((r*6/256)*36 + (g*6/256)*6 + (b*6/256)) / 256;
```

But i want to know how i can get 12bit rgb (4096) shades ?

Comment: Why not (r*216+g*36+b*6)/256/256? A higher weight for red than for green is uncommon. The problem with 12bit "direct RGB" is bit assignment - I'd suggest 4/5/3.

Comment: (What is *ASCII video*?)

Comment: my script convert mp4 video into ascii characters video. video display in ascii characters. in javascript i can't get more then 256 colors ascii video. or i have to use val += "<span style=\"color: rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+"); \">"+ this.getChar(val) +"</span>"; for full color ascii video output but span style tag make video very slow because it rendering span style color tag on every character, please see my this question maybe you answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72944933/need-pure-javascript-solution-instead-of-using-html-style-tag-for-fatest-rgb-col

Comment: Possibly useful: https://observablehq.com/@tmcw/octree-color-quantization

Comment: Wouldn't you simply divide the `r`, `g`, and `b` components by `16`, round or truncate them as you choose, and then recombine them as `256 * r + 16 * g + b`?